# Firebase ML Kit (Text_detection) - getConfident() return NULL

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition, vision-api

I am implementing firebase's Recognize text in images in my Android App. I can successfully get the result from the API by block/line/element.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text

My question is,  in the result data package, when I use `getConfidence()` in block/line/element, all return "NULL". However, when I test the API in the Cloud Vision API page and in the API demo page, there is confident return in the JSON.

Anyone know if there is way to get the confidence of the block/line/element

Answer (score 0):

For on-device Text Recognition we - sadly - do not provide confidence numbers at this moment. As part of an upcoming update we may reconsider this. FYI, the challenge is that it's not trivial to maintain calibration of confidence levels between updates to the underlying models.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I am using the cloud version (i.e. getCloudTextRecognizer()). It still has no value for the confidence number. @chrisito

Comment: Do you think you can provide the code example up until you get the NULLs that should be the confidence?

Comment: The confidence is only available if you use cloud with DENSE_MODEL  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/FirebaseVisionText.Line#public-float-getconfidence